# Как получить картинку на сервере?

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно передать картинку на сервер вот код который это делает

Я картинку вкладываю в `zip` apхив, потом этот архив раскладываю на `byte[]` вот так

```
File zipToSend = new File(zipPath);

        byte[] zipPhotosBytes = new byte[(int) zipToSend.length()];

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        BufferedInputStream bos = null;

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(zipToSend);
            bos = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (bos != null) {
                    bos.close();
                }
                if (fis != null) {
                    fis.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

и у меня получается `byte[] zipPhotosBytes` который хранит полный поток байтов и его я уже передаю в методе

```
public static JSONObject sentJsonToServer(final URL url, final byte[] data) {

    ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    Future<JSONObject> objectFuture = ex.submit(new Callable<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public JSONObject call() throws Exception {

            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/zip");
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
                urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                urlConnection.connect();
                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                bos.write(data);
                bos.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (bos != null) {
                        bos.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

//              returns POST request
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                return getJSONFromUrl(urlConnection);
            } else {
                throw new NullPointerException();
            }
        }
    });

    JSONObject responseJson = null;

    try {
        responseJson = objectFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return responseJson;
}
```

Но на сервере почему то формируется просто файл который нельзя ни открыть, ничего нельзя с ним сделать... Хотя вес файла который я передаю и который получается на сервере совпадает, значит байты не теряются...

Может мне нужно что то добавить в код ?

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле проблема была только в том, что я создавал массив байтов конкретного размера, но не заполнял его ничем... Поэтому на сервере я получал пустой файл, нужно было добавить эту строчку в код

```
try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(zipToSend);
        bos = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

        ---->  bos.read(zipPhotosBytes);


    }
```

И после этого я смог получить полный файл

Answer (score 0):

Для zip-файла корректнее будет использовать вот [это](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html).

Comment: чем это эффективнее, чем bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream()); ?

Comment: не знаю, чем эффективнее, но проще в том плане, что зипование пройдет под капотом

Comment: Так мне не нужно зиповать его, я уже передаю File zipToSend = new File(zipPath); путь к файлу который зипирован... Или я не так понимаю?

Comment: можно и не пользоваться ZipOutputStream. Однако Вы написали, что зипуете картинку и отправляете на сервер. Так вот, зиповать можно через ZipOutputStream. Вот [тут](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) отличный пример заполнения массива байтов.